# telerik scheduler issue in internet explorer

Tags: .net, internet-explorer, model-view-controller, telerik, kendo-scheduler

I am using Scheduler in one of our .NET MVC projects. Scheduler is not updating/creating appointments. This issue is being faced in Internet Explorer only. This issue does not occur on development machine but on server.

1. dev machine + internet explorer... No issue
2. dev machine + other browsers... No issue
3. Server + other browsers... No issue
4. Server + Internet Explorer 11 (with or without compatibility mode).. Data not being saved or updated

I.E. Debugger console (F12) does not show any errors. Can someone guide to resolve this issue.

Here is my code

```
@using Kendo.Mvc.UI;
@model List<pc.Web.Models.Scheduler.TaskViewModel>
<div class="panel panel-primary">
   <div class="panel-heading">
    Interview Scheduler
    <span class="pull-right badge">Use the scheduler to create available time slots</span>
</div>
<div class="panel-body">
    @(Html.Kendo().Scheduler<pc.Web.Models.Scheduler.TaskViewModel>()
            .Date(DateTime.Now)
            .StartTime(new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, DateTime.Now.Month, DateTime.Now.Day, 7, 00, 00))
            .Name("scheduler")
            .Height(950)
            .ShowWorkHours()
            .MajorTick(30)
            .MinorTickCount(1)
            .WorkDayStart(new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, DateTime.Now.Month, DateTime.Now.Day, 7, 0, 0))
            .WorkDayEnd(new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, DateTime.Now.Month, DateTime.Now.Day, 18, 0, 0))
            .Snap(true)
            .Selectable(true)
            .Views(views =>
            {
                views.WorkWeekView();
            })
            .Selectable(true)
            .AllDaySlot(true)
            .CurrentTimeMarker(true)
            .Pdf(pdf => pdf.FileName($"Scheduler_Details_{DateTime.Now.ToString("dd_mm_yyyy_hh_mm")}.pdf").ProxyURL(Url.Action("Pdf_Export_Save", "Grid")))
            .Toolbar(t => t.Pdf())
            .DataSource(d => d
                .Model(m => m.Id(f => f.TaskID))
                .Read("Read", "Scheduler")
                .Create("Create", "Scheduler")
                .Destroy("Destroy", "Scheduler")
                .Update("Update", "Scheduler")
            )
            .BindTo(Model)
            .Events(events => events.Save("reload"))
    )
</div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
function reload() { window.location.reload(); }    
</script>
```

Thanks

Comment: First tell us what version of I.E ? Do you have any js error in F12 ?

Comment: I am checking in Internet Explorer 11, tested with compatibilitiy mode off/on. F12 console does not show any errors.

Comment: Does the scheduler demo on Telerik have the same behaviour. Could you have the same behaviour with a simple test project ? Please edit those informations in your question so people dont have to read comment.

Comment: Question editing to add that information, thanks for pointing that. Telerik demo is working fine.

Comment: Place trace or debug from the Button to the data base save.

Comment: Please add information about the version you are using. Check if your version us up to date. I can not reproduce this behaviour.

Comment: I am using version 2015.2.902.440 (taken from properties of kendo.mvc.dll)